# ggplot - legend as y-axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have the following graph

[image]

Is it possible to add the legend labels (HPD and Quantile) under the respective boxplots? Also can i get rid of the white bar in the middle?

My code isthe following:

```
p <- ggplot(Results.Baseline,aes(x=Inference, y=Results, fill=Method)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
  geom_boxplot()+facet_wrap(~Method)+ facet_wrap(~Model)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.95, linetype="dashed", color = "red")
```

I basically want something like this just under all boxplots: 
[image]

```
Here is my data: 

   data <- structure(list(Results = c(0.234375, 0.203125, 0.234375, 0.203125, 
0.21875, 0.203125), Model = c("Baseline 1", "Baseline 1", "Baseline 1", 
"Baseline 1", "Baseline 1", "Baseline 1"), Method = c("Quantile", 
"Quantile", "Quantile", "Quantile", "Quantile", "Quantile"), 
    Inference = c("HMDM", "HMDM", "HMDM", "HMDM", "HMDM", "HMDM"
    )), .Names = c("Results", "Model", "Method", "Inference"), row.names = c("1:nrow(transitions)", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Does `+ theme(legend.position = "bottom")`do what you want?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are after.  Do you want to add the labels under the boxplot keys in the legend or under each boxplot in the plot or...?  Is the white bar you are referring to the space between the two panels?  If so see `panel.spacing` in `theme()`.

Comment: @aosmith I have added a picture showing what I am after

Comment: @tifu No, I basically want to get rid of the legend and just add the labels as in the second picture.

Comment: I would approach this by making a dataset with one row for each combo of Inference, Method, and Model and a column for `y` position (looks like maybe you want to put labels at `y = 0`?).  Then you can plot Method as labels with `geom_text()`.

Comment: Need data to help, but to answer your question about removing the white bar in the middle this theme will help - `  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
               panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color="white"))`

Comment: @Mike Thanks that worked perfectly! I have also added some of my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added more data so that I can replicate your graph better. You can
>   use `geom_text` to add the `Method` labels to the graph. You have to
>   only keep one label per box plot which is why I created the `datalabs`
>   dataframe. Also you did not need two `facet_wraps` in your plot. Does
>   this help answer your question?

```
    data <- structure(list(Results = c(0.234375, 0.203125, 0.234375, 0.203125, 
        0.21875, 0.203125), Model = c("Baseline 1", "Baseline 1", "Baseline

 1", 
    "Baseline 1", "Baseline 1", "Baseline 1"), Method = c("Quantile", 
    "Quantile", "Quantile", "Quantile", "Quantile", "Quantile"), 
    Inference = c("HMDM", "HMDM", "HMDM", "HMDM", "HMDM", "HMDM"
    )), .Names = c("Results", "Model", "Method", "Inference"), row.names = c("1:nrow(transitions)", 
    "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), class = "data.frame")


    data2 <- structure(list(Results = c(0.234375, 0.203125, 0.234375, 0.203125, 
    0.21875, 0.203125), Model = c("Baseline 2", "Baseline 2", "Baseline 2", 
    "Baseline 2", "Baseline 2", "Baseline 2"), Method = c("HPD", 
    "HPD", "HPD", "HPD", "HPD", "HPD"), 
    Inference = c("Eco. Inf.", "Eco. Inf.", "Eco. Inf.", "Eco. Inf.",
                  "Eco. Inf.", "Eco. Inf."
    )), .Names = c("Results", "Model", "Method", "Inference"), row.names = c("1:nrow(transitions)", 
    "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), class = "data.frame")

    data3 <- rbind(data,data2)

    data4 <- mutate(data3, Method = ifelse(Method == "Quantile",
                                           "HPD","Quantile"),
                          Inference = ifelse(Inference == "HMDM","Eco. Inf.",
                                             "HMDM"))

    data5 <- rbind(data3,data4)

    datalabs <- data5 %>% 
                group_by(Method,Model) %>% 
                arrange(Method,Model) %>% 
                filter(row_number()==1)

    ggplot(data5,aes(x=Inference, y=Results, fill=Method)) + 
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
      geom_boxplot()+
      facet_wrap(~Model)+
      geom_hline(yintercept=0.95, linetype="dashed", color = "red")+
      geom_text(data = datalabs, aes(label=Method) ,
                nudge_y = -.1)+
      theme_bw() +
      theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
      theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
            strip.background = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color="white"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thats perfect! Thank you so much.